# WPF Application with OnScreenKeyboard on Windows Tablet

Tags: c#, wpf, on-screen-keyboard

I am building a WPF Application that is going to be used on Desktop as well as on a Surface Pro Tablet running the Win10 Creators Update.

If a Textbox gets Focus the onscreenkeyboard of Win10 should open on the bottom of the screen and move the application up the screen to push the focused element back into view.

I have implemented [WpfTabTib](https://github.com/maximcus/WPFTabTip) which worked pretty well until we updated the tablet to the creators version. Technically it is still working but with an ugly animation moving the window up, down and up again to open the keyboard.

Having read that microsoft adjusted the behaviour of the keyboard to match the uwp behaviour I have updated my .Net framework to 4.6.2 without the hoped result. It seems Microsoft doesn't care for this behaviour.

Does anyone have the same problem or an different approach for me ?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: Updating the Tablet to an Insider Preview of the coming Windows Fall Update changed the behaviour again: The opening animation is now a little better, but still far from nice. And as new problem closing the osk doesn't move the application back down.

Comment: Good question!...

Comment: Did you try to recompile for .Net Framework 4.7? there are some improvements for WPF

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your reply! Sadly I did try this already without any success...